# Read spark column with semicolon using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a column from a dataframe that contains ;(semicolon) using Spark SQL. The name of the column is `Profit &amp; Gain`. While the name of the column is displayed the same way when I query the schema, I am unable to use it when I try to query on the column using select clause.

```
spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[2,3]], ["id", "Profit &amp; Gain"]).createOrReplaceTempView("dex")

%sql select 
`Profit &amp; Gain` from dex
```

Error is:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'select \n`'(line 2, pos 0)

== SQL ==
select 
`Profit &amp
^^^
```

I know that ';' in a column name is definitely a bad practice, but I would like to know if there a way to get over this. I tried enclosing the same using backticks, which didn't work.

Note: This seems to be working quite well using pyspark,but spark sql fails to.
Also another thing I noticed is that any character apart from ;(semicolon) works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you please add the code to reproduce the problem? For me the following code works: `df=spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[2,3]], ["id", "Profit &amp; Gain"])        
df.select("Profit &amp; Gain").show()`

Comment: @werner Edits Done!

Comment: @halfwind22 - What spark version are you using ?

Comment: @Vaebhav Azure Databricks Runtime 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)

Answer (score 0):

Using `backticks` to escape the required column is working fine -

```
sql.createDataFrame([[1,2],[2,3]], ["id", "Profit &amp; Gain"]).createOrReplaceTempView("dex")

sql.sql("""
    select 
        `Profit &amp; Gain`
    from dex
    """
).show()

+-----------------+
|Profit &amp; Gain|
+-----------------+
|                2|
|                3|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Even the following is working spark.sql("select `Profit &amp; Gain` from dex").show() ,but not  %sql select 
`Profit &amp; Gain` from dex

Comment: Backticks aren't helping either.

Comment: so you want it to work with `%sql` interpreter within Databricks ?

Comment: long story short, YES. Maybe the query parsing techniques corresponding to spark.sql and SELECT command for Databricks SQL are different